# TypeError: this.props.dispatch is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Кто может подсказать в чем проблема. Хочу вызвать модальное окно, но при нажатии на кнопку login или Register появляется следующая ошибка TypeError: this.props.dispatch is not a function. Уже голову сломал, почему не видит функцию диспатч. Буду очень благодарен, если кто-нибудь подскажет в чём проблема.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { openModal } from "../modal/index";
import Login from "../auth/Login";
import Register from "../auth/Register";

class Navbar extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.register = this.register.bind(this);
   }

  login() {
    this.props.dispatch(
      openModal({content: <Login />,title: "Login"}));
  }
  register() {
    this.props.dispatch(
      openModal({content: <Register />,title: "Register"}));
  }

  render() {
      const guestLinks = (
      <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li className="nav-item">
          <button
            className="m-1 btn-sm btn btn-outline-primary mt-1"
            onClick={this.register}>Register</button>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <button
            className="m-1 btn-sm btn btn-outline-primary mt-1"
            onClick={this.login}>Login</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );

    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light mb-4">
        <div className="container">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">
            Domras
          </Link>
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#mobile-nav">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon" />
          </button>

          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mobile-nav">
            <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/profiles">
                  Driver
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Navbar);
```

Ниже код component.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { closeModal } from './actions';
import './styles.css';

class Modal extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    modal: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
  }
  close() {
    this.props.dispatch(closeModal());
  }

  render() {
    const { isOpen, title, content} = this.props.modal;

    if (!isOpen) return null;
    return (
      <div className="modal in" >
        <div className="modal-dialog">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title">{title}</h5>
              <button type="button" className="close" onClick={this.close}>
                <span>&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              {content}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    modal: state.modal
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Modal);
```

код actions.js

```
export const OPEN_MODAL = 'OPEN_MODAL';
export const CLOSE_MODAL = 'CLOSE_MODAL';

export function openModal(options){
    const { title, btnText, content } = options;
    return dispatch => {
         dispatch({
        type: OPEN_MODAL,
        title, btnText, content
    })
}
}
export function closeModal(){
    return dispatch =>
     { dispatch({
        type: CLOSE_MODAL
    })
}
}
```

код modalReducers.js

```
import { OPEN_MODAL, CLOSE_MODAL } from "./actions"

const initialState = {
    isOpen: false,
    title: '',
    btnText: 'OK',
    content: null
}
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case OPEN_MODAL:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isOpen: true,
                title: action.title,
                btnText: action.btnText,
                content: action.content
            });
        case CLOSE_MODAL:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                isOpen: false,
            });
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

код app.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
          <Modal />
            <Navbar />

            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
            <div className="container">...
```

код Login.js это должно открываться в модальном окне

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { loginUser } from "../../actions/authActions.js";
import TextFieldGroup from "../common/TextFieldGroup.js";

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      errors: {}
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }

    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.errors
      });
    }
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };

    this.props.loginUser(userData);
  }

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="login">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
              <h1 className="display-4 text-center">Log In</h1>
              <p className="lead text-center">
                Sign in to your DevConnector account
              </p>
              <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <TextFieldGroup
                  placeholder="Email Address"
                  name="email"
                  type="email"
                  value={this.state.email}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.email}
                />

                <TextFieldGroup
                  placeholder="Password"
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                  value={this.state.password}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  error={errors.password}
                />

                <input type="submit" className="btn btn-info btn-block mt-4" />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loginUser })(Login);
```

Comment: Приложите код как Вы используете этот компонент. У Вас явно прописано что функция `dispatch` это обязательный пропс и судя по ошибке Вы её не передаете.

Comment: @Grundy, @0xdb - это не дубликат. Здесь проблема как я писал выше в том что в компонент не передается `props.dispatch`.